# java.lang.NullPointerException when trying to write to an excel file:

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am getting a java.lang.NullPointerException, normally I have no issue finding  the culprit but this time I am very confused.

First I confirmed my JPQL is working like so:

```
   List<ShopOrder> shopOrders = poRepository.getShopOrder(id);

            for (ShopOrder<?> order : shopOrders) {

                System.out.println(order.toString());
```

and in the console I got:

```
    ShopOrder [po_id=2, po_number=323, po_due_date=2015-06-16, po_part_id=3, part_quantity=44, part_id=1, part_number=3241, part_decription=Train Hub, plasma_hrs=33.0000, gring_hours=10.0000, mill_hrs=2.0000, breakpress_hrs=4.0000]

    ShopOrder [po_id=1, po_number=234, po_due_date=2015-06-09, po_part_id=1, part_quantity=3423, part_id=1, part_number=3241, part_decription=Train Hub, plasma_hrs=33.0000, gring_hours=10.0000, mill_hrs=2.0000, breakpress_hrs=4.0000]
```

Then I decided I need a more specific error. Here is the full method of the snippet from above:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/generateShopOrder/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Timed
    public void generate(@PathVariable Long id) throws URISyntaxException {
        System.out.println("po id to generate = " + id);

        List<ShopOrder> shopOrders = poRepository.getShopOrder(id);

        for (ShopOrder<?> order : shopOrders) {

            System.out.println(order.toString());
            try {
                jobOrderGenerator = new JobOrderGenerator(shopOrders);
                System.out.println("Printing inside try statement: PO number " + order.getPo_number() + "\nPrinting part id " + order.getPart_id());

            } catch (InterruptedException exception) {

                System.out.println("Something is null " + exception);
                exception.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.print("Was not able to create job orders,IOexception " + ex);

            } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
                System.out.print("Invalid file format: " + e);

            }
        }
```

However, as you can see in the error (posted at the bottom) is only printing out the println statement saying "something null".

Then I thought maybe there is something going on with my file, which is in my resource folder, so I checked it by doing the following:

```
public JobOrderGenerator(List<ShopOrder> shopOrder) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException, InterruptedException {

        if(file.exists() && file.isDirectory()){
            System.out.println("Was was found");
        } else {
            System.out.println("File was NOT found");
        }

        for (ShopOrder shopOrder1 : shopOrder) {

            writeToSpecificCell(2, 1, sheetNumber, shopOrder1.getPo_number()); //Po Number
            writeToSpecificCell(7, 3, sheetNumber, shopOrder1.getPo_number()); //Part Number
            LocalDate date = shopOrder1.getPo_due_date();
            String dateToString = date.toString();
            writeToSpecificCell(1, 2, sheetNumber, dateToString); //Due_Date
            writeToSpecificCell(7, 5, sheetNumber, Integer.toString(shopOrder1.getPart_quantity())); //Quantity
            //writeToSpecificCell(1,2,sheetNumber, shopOrder.get); //Material
            writeToSpecificCell(8, 3, sheetNumber, shopOrder1.getPart_decription()); //Part Description
            //writeToSpecificCell(1,2,sheetNumber, shopOrder.getCustomer()); //Customer
            writeToSpecificCell(10, 1, sheetNumber, shopOrder1.getMachine_number()); //Machine

            sheetNumber++;

        }
    }

    void writeToSpecificCell(int rowNumber, int cellNumber, int sheetNumber, String value) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {

        try {

            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(sheetNumber);

            XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(rowNumber);
            XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(cellNumber);

            if (cell == null) {
                cell = row.createCell(cellNumber);
            }
            cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
            cell.setCellValue(value);

            workbook.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println("Error is writeToSpecificCell class " + e);
        }
    }
```

This told me it is failing before the if statement in the constructor is not even getting to executed. This is where I am wondering where to look next. Any advice?

Error:

```
Hibernate: select po0_.id as col_0_0_, po0_.po_number as col_1_0_, po0_.due_date as col_2_0_, partlist1_.id as col_3_0_, partlist1_.part_quantity as col_4_0_, part2_.id as col_5_0_, part2_.part_number as col_6_0_, part2_.part_description as col_7_0_, part2_.plasma_hrs_per_part as col_8_0_, part2_.grind_hrs_per_part as col_9_0_, part2_.mill_hrs_per_part as col_10_0_, part2_.brakepress_hrs_per_part as col_11_0_ from T_PO po0_ inner join T_PO_PART partlist1_ on po0_.id=partlist1_.po_id inner join T_PART part2_ on partlist1_.part_id=part2_.id where po0_.id=?
Hibernate: select po0_.id as col_0_0_, po0_.po_number as col_1_0_, po0_.due_date as col_2_0_, partlist1_.id as col_3_0_, partlist1_.part_quantity as col_4_0_, part2_.id as col_5_0_, part2_.part_number as col_6_0_, part2_.part_description as col_7_0_, part2_.plasma_hrs_per_part as col_8_0_, part2_.grind_hrs_per_part as col_9_0_, part2_.mill_hrs_per_part as col_10_0_, part2_.brakepress_hrs_per_part as col_11_0_ from T_PO po0_ inner join T_PO_PART partlist1_ on po0_.id=partlist1_.po_id inner join T_PART part2_ on partlist1_.part_id=part2_.id where po0_.id=?
ShopOrder [po_id=2, po_number=323, po_due_date=2015-06-16, po_part_id=3, part_quantity=44, part_id=1, part_number=3241, part_decription=Train Hub, plasma_hrs=33.0000, gring_hours=10.0000, mill_hrs=2.0000, breakpress_hrs=4.0000]
ShopOrder [po_id=1, po_number=234, po_due_date=2015-06-09, po_part_id=1, part_quantity=3423, part_id=1, part_number=3241, part_decription=Train Hub, plasma_hrs=33.0000, gring_hours=10.0000, mill_hrs=2.0000, breakpress_hrs=4.0000]
[ERROR] com.htd.aop.logging.LoggingAspect - Exception in com.htd.web.rest.PoResource.generate() with cause = null
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.htd.domain.JobOrderGenerator.<init>(JobOrderGenerator.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.htd.web.rest.PoResource.generate(PoResource.java:302) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.htd.web.rest.PoResource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cfcd338a.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
```

-----------Update---------

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Inject
    private Environment env;

    @Pointcut("within(com.htd.repository..*) || within(com.htd.service..*) || within(com.htd.web.rest..*)")
    public void loggingPointcut() {}

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "loggingPointcut()", throwing = "e")
    public void logAfterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable e) {
        if (env.acceptsProfiles(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT)) {
            log.error("Exception in {}.{}() with cause = {}", joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(),
                    joinPoint.getSignature().getName(), e.getCause(), e);
        } else {
            log.error("Exception in {}.{}() with cause = {}", joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(),
                    joinPoint.getSignature().getName(), e.getCause());
        }
    }
```

---------Update 2------------

This is the statement executing the error:

```
if (env.acceptsProfiles(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT)) {
            log.error("Exception in {}.{}() with cause = {}", joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(),
                    joinPoint.getSignature().getName(), e.getCause(), e);
```

-----------Update 3------------
I did this to check if Environment was null and I did not see anything in the console.

```
@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "loggingPointcut()", throwing = "e")
    public void logAfterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable e) {

        if (this.env==null){
            log.error("Environment is null");
        }
```

-------------Update 4------------

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
```

This is what is returning the java.lang.NullPointerException, it never even gets to:

```
file = new File(classLoader.getResource("Shop-Order.xlsx").getFile());
```

Which was why I could not check if the file was null. Still looking into why.Once I solve this I might need to change the title of this post.

----------UPDATE 5--------------

I needed this since it was in my resource file which will be in my jar file. I will be writing to the file (file within a file)

```
inputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Shop-Order.xlsx");
```

NOW I have to figure out how to pass this as a file to apache poi

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
```

It needs a file, not a inputstream.

----------Update 6---------------

After I completed update 6 I was able to figure out what was failing. The below method. In the console it prints:

```
Inside writeToSpecificCell before try statement 2 0 123
```

and

```
Inside writeToSpecificCell at the beginning of try statement


void writeToSpecificCell(int rowNumber, int cellNumber, int sheetNumber, String value) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Inside writeToSpecificCell before try statement "+cellNumber+" "+sheetNumber+" "+value);
        try {
            System.out.println("Inside writeToSpecificCell at the beginnning of try statement");
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(sheetNumber);

            XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(rowNumber);
            XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(cellNumber);

            if (cell == null) {
                cell = row.createCell(cellNumber);
            }
            cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
            cell.setCellValue(value);
            System.out.println("Inside writeToSpecificCell at the end of try statement");
                 workbook.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked your Logging aspect? "[ERROR] com.htd.aop.logging.LoggingAspect - Exception in com.htd.web.rest.PoResource.generate() with cause = null" does not say "Something is null", but an Exception was thrown where ex.getCause() == null.

Comment: @AndreasAumayr just updated the code. Looking closer at it now too.

Comment: @AndreasAumayr the "@AfterThrowing" is catching the null exception but it is not telling me where it is so I am still wondering what the heck could be null.

Comment: Probably the variable env is null at time of execution. Could you verify that the injection works as expected?

Comment: @AndreasAumayr please see update 3

Comment: Seems that the logging aspect is working as expected. Just realized that the aspect is declaread as 'after throwing'. So the problem is probably indeed within the other code..

Comment: @AndreasAumayr I created every catch I could think of. The list is being initialized from the repository. The class is able to find the file excel file. What the heck is null? I will continue you dig deeper. Maybe I just need to step away for a moment.

Comment: could you please write the complete output of your given sample program? there are some debug lines like '"po id to generate = " + id' that are not shown within the result.. EDIT: Just in case you're using eclipse: Start your application in debug mode an add an exception breakpoint that breaks on NPE.

Comment: @AndreasAumayr please see update 4

Answer (score 1):

Can't be sure because the source is not shown entirely, but it seems logical that `file` is null. It is the only thing referenced before the first output in the constructor.
Try this

```
    if (file == null) {
        System.out.println("file is null");
    } else if (file.exists() && file.isDirectory()){
        System.out.println("Was was found");
    } else {
        System.out.println("File was NOT found");
    }
```

Normally, for solving these issues you should ONLY need to look at the stack trace, it will tell you right away where the issue is. If that doesn't work, as @AndreasAumayr suggested, use a debugger and either break on the Exception (the icon looks like "J!") or on the line mentioned in the stack trace.